Executing EFI Shell script via PXE
I want to have a way to execute low-level maintenance task via the EFI Shell and have a corresponding entry in the Boot Menu. It essentially should execute an EFI Shell script. From there I can call all the necessary actions.
Is it possible to use the PXE boot function of EFI to download an nsh EFI shell script and execute it?
So far I only found references to EFI applications.
Or as an alternative, is it possible to add the execution of an EFI script to the boot configuration via bcfg command?
Then I could put use this script to use TFTP (see Copying files to EFI shell through network) and download the needed things and execute them.
While I can add the path to an EFI script to the boot menu with bcfg selecting it returns a failure dialog:


You can add files as a boot option like bcfg boot add 3 osloader.efi "My OS", but yeah it doesn't look like you can load a .nsh shell script that way. In UEFI systems, PXE just downloads and runs an executable .efi image as well. Depending on your bios, you may be able to add/enable a "Launch EFI Script" boot option, but it's not universal
